# Proving every subgroup of a nilpotent group is subnormal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group, i.e. $\exists$ an upper central series:

$1\triangleleft Z_1(G)\triangleleft Z_2(G)\triangleleft ....\triangleleft Z_k(G)=G$

Where $\frac{Z_{i+1}}{Z_i}=Z(\frac{G}{Z_i})$

To show that every subgroup of $G$ is subnormal, let $H \leq G$. Then we can multiply every term of the upper central series of $G$ by $H$ to get a new series:

$H\leq HZ_1(G)\leq HZ_2(G)\leq ....\leq HZ_k(G)=G$

If we can show that $HZ_i(G)\triangleleft HZ_{i+1}(G)$ then we are done.

I am having trouble doing this. There was another post on stack exchange similiar to this from awhile back but I found the answers inadequate so I thought i'd ask again. Thanks!

Comment: Don't we want $[HZ_i,HZ_{i+1}] \leq HZ_i$?

Comment: You seem to have written $\rhd$ where you mean $\lhd$. I think you mean $1 \lhd Z_1(G) \lhd Z_2(G)$ and you want to prove $HZ_i \unlhd HZ_{i+1}$. So $[HZ_i,HZ_{i+1}] = [H,H][H,Z_i][H,Z_{i+1}][Z_i,Z_{i+1}] \le HZ_i$ as required.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, it was my mistake, I am going to edit my question, so if you want to edit your response go for it. That is a great way to show normality, by far the simplest I've seen

Comment: @DerekHolt allow me to tag you please, what does the notation $[HZ_i,\ HZ_{i+1}]$ mean? and is it standard?

Comment: @NotaChoice Yes it is standard notation for commutators. For subsets $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$, define $[H,K] := \langle [h,k] \mid h \in H, k \in K \rangle$, where $[h,k]:=h^{-1}k^{-1}hk$.

Comment: ok, can I ask how do you write it as an internal product of the 4 subgroups, and why this product is a subgroup of $HZ_i$? $[H,H]]$ is trivial... is there some rule for this, just taking all possible 4 combinations? @DerekHolt

Comment: The expansion of the product follows from the standard commutator identities (see the Wikipedia page for example) and the property that $[H,K]$ is normalized by both $H$ and $K$ for subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$.  Then $[H,H] \le H$ and the other three terms are contained in $Z_i$, because it is a central series.

Comment: why is $[H,Z_{i+1}]$ contained in $Z_i$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: As I said, it's because $Z_i$ is a central series.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks! Can I ask for more? shouldn't be there some shorter way to show that $HZ_i$ is normal in $HZ_{i+1}$ without using this commutator identity? I mean maybe this fact is true because of something precise that we just need to point out?

Comment: @NotaChoice It is reasonable to ask me for further explanation of my comment, but it is not reasonable to ask me a separate question in a comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I am asking about the original question, why every subgroup of a nilpotent group is subnormal, it seems like going through the commutator identity is a long way, unless you confirm it is the only way to go.

Comment: @DerekHolt again, I couldn't convince myself, how does the property $Z_{i+1}/Z_i\subset Z(G/Z_i)$ imply that $[H, Z_{i+1}]\subset Z_i$ ?

Comment: $Z_{i+1}/Z_i \le Z(G/Z_i) \Leftrightarrow [G,Z_{i+1}] \le Z_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (in case of finite groups): use the “normalizers grow” principle in nilpotent groups.

Comment: Are you sure you are not assuming that $G$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I see there is no finiteness condition. Will adjust.